# How can I add a StyleCop rule suppression without StyleCop installed on my machine?

Tags: c#, attributes, stylecop, suppress-warnings

I would like to add a StyleCop `SuppressMessageAttribute` to some code but I don't want to require StyleCop to be installed.

Does my project need to reference the StyleCop binaries and if so, which ones? Also, is the StyleCop `SuppressMessageAttribute` different to the `System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessageAttribute`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need stylecop installed or referenced to add a suppression. StyleCop uses the standard code analysis SuppressMessageAttribute which ships in the .NET Framework.